# Where is react web example code using fetch and life cycle components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm making web using react.

Most of my react code is from airbnb style (https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates)

but I can't find How to use Fetch API in react web.

can you recommend a good example?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this article
https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/

It uses `axios` but you can follow the same pattern and replace the `axios` code with

```
fetch('http://api.exampledomain.com/api/search')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((jsonData) => {
  //handle json data processing here
  console.log(jsonData);
});
```